# How to describe what is conformal bootstrap and what's its application in renormalization group?

Tags: renormalization, conformal-field-theory

As I asked in title, I would like to know what is conformal bootstrap and what's its application in renormalization group, and how to understand it (in a simple way).

Comment: http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/172180/looking-for-intro-to-conformal-bootstrap