# Japanese book on 3D Ising model and higher dimensional CFT

Tags: conformal-field-theory, spacetime-dimensions, ising-model, specific-reference

So I came across this [Japanese book](https://www.amazon.co.jp/-/en/%E4%B8%AD%E5%B1%B1-%E5%84%AA/dp/4781914608/ref=mp_s_a_1_3?dchild=1&qid=1629027490&s=books&sr=1-3&text=%E4%B8%AD%E5%B1%B1%20%E5%84%AA) by Yu Nakayama on the conformal bootstrap, called "高次元共形場理論への招待―3次元臨界Ising模型を解く" (Invitation to High Dimensional Conformal Field Theory - Solving 3D Critical Ising Model)

Do you know if there is an English edition? It is the only book that I know on the conformal bootstrap so it's really interesting.

Comment: Nakayama is a very approachable person, you could ask them directly, You can find their email address on [inspirehep](https://inspirehep.net/authors/1020937).

Comment: Also see: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/172180

Comment: @AccudentalFourierTransform Unfortunately I couldn't find his current email address. Would you be able to share it?

Comment: "Accudental" sounds like a toothpaste brand. Go to the inspire link and click here: https://i.imgur.com/86xHPgQ.png

Comment: email on his homepage! https://yunakayama.neko9.org

Comment: @trula Not the same Nakayama...

Comment: "Accudental sounds like a toothpaste brand" is probably one of the best non-technical comments I've read on this site.

Comment: @AccidentalFourierTransform hahaha mb. trying to type on the phone :D

Comment: @AccidentalFourierTransform I am really amazed that I don't know that contact feature at inspire. Thank you for that!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After corresponding with Yu Nakayama, he told me that unfortunately there is no English edition. He referred me to a similar review by David Simons-Duffin, [TASI Lectures on the Conformal Bootstrap](https://arxiv.org/abs/1602.07982).